# means stack route issue 'method is not undefined' halt the application

Tags: model-view-controller, express, ubuntu-14.04, mean-stack

While Working with mean stack. I got error of route files when run `grunt`

```
packages/custom/channel/server/routes/channels.js
 18 |        .post(auth.requiresLogin, channel.create);
                                       ^ 'channel' is not defined.
 20 |        .get(auth.isMongoId, channel.show)
                                  ^ 'channel' is not defined.
 21 |        .put(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.update)
                                                                        ^ 'channel' is not defined.
 22 |        .delete(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.destroy);
                                                                           ^ 'channel' is not defined.

>> 4 errors in 54 files
Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

below is the relevant code

#### ../server/routes/channels.js

```
module.exports = function(Channels, app, auth, database) {
    app.route('/channel')
        .get(channels.all)
        .post(auth.requiresLogin, channel.create); // line #18
    app.route('/channel/:channelId')
        .get(auth.isMongoId, channel.show)
        .put(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.update)
        .delete(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.destroy);
```

So far I understand this error is, that there must be a method `create` in controller so here is relevant controller code

#### ../server/controllers/channels.js

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var channel = new Channel(req.body);
    channel.user = req.user;

    channel.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Cannot save the channel'
            });
        }
        res.json(channel);

    });
};
```

Please tell me what wrong I am doing , there may be casing issue, file name issue or something else.

Kindly help me

Comment: Am I doing something wrong. i have asked 5 question since I join SO but o once is going to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to be exposed to your router with this line. Currently your router doesn't know what `channel` is.

`var channels = require('../controllers/channel')(Channels);`

Example:

```
module.exports = function(Channels, app, auth, database) {
    var channel = require('../controllers/channels')(Channels);
    app.route('/channel')
        .get(channels.all)
        .post(auth.requiresLogin, channel.create);
    app.route('/channel/:channelId')
        .get(auth.isMongoId, channel.show)
        .put(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.update)
        .delete(auth.isMongoId, auth.requiresLogin, hasAuthorization, channel.destroy);
```